# reopening class in initializer breaks attribute accessors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use an initializer in Rails 4.2 to add a method to an ActiveRecord model. However, simply reopening the class in the initializer breaks the existing attribute accessors.

model app/models/thing.rb:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

migration db/migrate/20160914144414_create_things.rb:

```
class CreateThings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :things do |t|
      t.integer :test_field
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

initializer config/initializers/thing.rb:

```
class Thing
  def self.new_method
    "hello"
  end
end
```

test file test/models/thing_test.rb:

```
require File.expand_path("../../test_helper", __FILE__)

class ThingTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    thing = Thing.new
    thing.test_field = 1
    puts thing.new_method
  end
end
```

When I run my test here's what I get:

```
❯❯❯ rtest test/models/thing_test.rb
  1) Error:
ThingTest#test_the_truth:
NoMethodError: undefined method `test_field=' for #<Thing:0x00000101464658>
    test/models/thing_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:ThingTest>'
```

If I use this alternate syntax to add the method to the class, it works:

```
Thing.class_eval do
  def self.new_method
    "hello"
  end
end
```

I guess I'm happy to do it this way, but I would like to know why it doesn't work just reopening the class.

Comment: I'm not creating the class in the initializer, I'm trying to reopen it and add a method. Its my understanding that Ruby allows this

Comment: The initializer is not executed first. The class already exists when the initializer runs.

Comment: I put a debugger statement at the top of the file. In the debugger I can query `Thing.superclass` and I get ActiveRecord::Base. I can create an instance of Thing and call test_field on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing is that you're not reopening the class: you're defining  a new one. In development and in tests your classes are loaded when they are first used. By defining `Thing` in your initializer you prevent your thing.rb file from ever being loaded.

When you use `Thing.class_eval` you're not defining a new class so rails loads `Thing` from thing.rb: at this point your are adding to `Thing` rather than replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

> I put a debugger statement at the top of the file. In the debugger I can query Thing.superclass and I get ActiveRecord::Base. I can create an instance of Thing and call test_field on it.

The mere act of observing the experiment alters its results. The class **does not** exist when you stop at debugger statement there. But it is **autoloaded** the moment you evaluate `Thing` in the debugger console.

What you could do in your real initializer is to trigger loading of the model, one way or another.

```
# initializers/thing.rb
Thing # trigger autoloading
class Thing
  ...
end


# or
require 'app/models/thing.rb' # load explicitly
class Thing
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that is not a conclusion I would have reached on my own!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happend because you declared method without inheritance. Your default accessors come from `ActiveRecord::Base`. So when you declared new method, you override everything from inheritor.

Comment: I get the same result if I use `class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base`